# Is every maximally independent subset of an abelian group a basis?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

According to Zorn's theorem, every abelian group with a torsion-free element has a maximally independent subset.

A basis of an abelian group $G$ is an independent generating subset of $G$. We are talking about a group, therefore any linear combination should imply $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination.

I would like to know if every maximally independent subset (call it $A$) of an abelian group $G$ is a basis of $G$ regardless of the order of $G$.

My guess is yes because if $A$ is not a basis then there exists $g \in G$, which cannot be generated by $A$ and thus $A \cup \{g\}$ is independent, which is contradictory since $A$ is already maximally independent.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In addition to the example in Paul Garrett's answer, you might think about the additive group of rational numbers, in which **every** set consisting of  single non-zero element is a maximal independent set, yet **no** such set generates the whole group.  ($\mathbb Q$ is not generated by any independent set.)

Answer (score 4):

Already in $G=\mathbb Z$, every non-zero element $n$ gives a maximal $\mathbb Z$-independent subset $\{n\}$, since joining any further non-zero element gives a non-trivial $\mathbb Z$-linear relation. But only $\{1\}$ and $\{-1\}$ generate $\mathbb Z$.